# getting html table data from parent row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an expandable html table row. After the row is expanded, there is a button below it and I want to get the data of the first column of the parent row when the button is clicked.

But my code keeps showing the label of my button instead of the data of the parent row:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btnedit').click(function () {
            alert($(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

**JSFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/knowmeifyou/5217hLac/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prev` to get previous tr

```
alert($(this).closest("tr").prev("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text());
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5217hLac/1/)